# Is it possible to access any file or dir within a non-accessible directory?

Tags: permissions, security, directory

Say I set my home /home/john directory as not readable for any other user. But I've forgotten to do so with some files within that directory, say ./.bashrc or ./Downloads/Presentation.ppt.
Now, if another user guesses path and name of those files (which is of course easy in case of /home/john/.bashrc) can they read/execute those files by pointing to them directly? Or is it impossible to access any file or directory within a non-accessible directory? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

When a directory has "x' (or searchable) permission, it is possible that specific files under a directory having for example 111 (--x--x--x) permission can be accessed if their name is known AND the permission of the destination file allows it.

Directories with 'r' permission allow programs such as ls to basically open the directory as a file and read it and thus report their contents to you the users.

Comment: so when a dir doesnt have the x (so rwx------ in my case) is it then impossible to access anything at all within that dir?

Comment: yep....in the above case if you are not the owner of the directory.